# What is the meaning of "shout observations"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> The  women  who  sold  their  bodies  at  bargain  prices  until  dawn  moved  around  the 
>   house after eleven in the morning, when the heat from the stained glass became unbearable, and they were obliged 
>   to  live  their  domestic  life  walking  naked  through  the  house  while  they  **shouted  observations**  on  the  night's 
>   adventures.
>
> [Source: Garcia Marquez, Memories of my melancholy whores, translated by E. Grossman]

I cannot make sense of the part saying "...*shouted observations* on the night's adventures". What does it mean for one to *shout observations*?

I looked up the verb *shout* which basically means:

> to cry aloud and say something

and *observation* which means:

> process of watching something or something that is being watched.

So, what I conclude of "shout observations" is that they described scenes of lovemaking at night by shouting. Am I correct?

Comment: Look up the noun "observation" and the verb "to shout", and tell us what you conclude, and what doubts, if any, remain.

Comment: @DanBron I looked up the words and edited the post accordingly, but I am not yet sure what it means.

Comment: Thanks for the edit! I think what's tripping you up is you stopped at the first sense of *observation* listed in your dictionary. There is [another, usually listed second](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/observation#observation_8): *a written or spoken comment about something that you have seen, heard, or felt*. We're talking about *shouting*, here, which is verbal, so the *written* in that definition is not relevant, so we can conclude that *shouted observations* means "someone shouting comments about something they have seen, heard, or felt".

Comment: Thank you, I guess now I understand what the author meant.

Comment: No problem. In general, if a passage confuses you, you should look up the culprit words, and reinterpret the passage; if it's still nonsensical, you should continue to read more word-senses til you find one which results in a meaningful and contextually-supported interpretation. This method has its limits (probably the first of which is knowing when you're dealing with idiom or even metaphor!), but it's a good initial approach. If English is not your mother tongue, then having a translating dictionary handy is also helpful. I imagine *shout* has a direct translation, for example.

Comment: This needs more than a couple of quick checks in a dictionary. 'Shout' is not found as a transitive verb all that frequently, and is rarely coupled with 'observations' as DO. I think it would sound very unidiomatic without the 'on the night's adventures' here. Much more common is the quotative-verb usage ('Get out!' he shouted.), and probably the intransitive usage, usually with 'about'. This probably explains the incongruity one perceives with 'shout[ing] observations'. A more usual collocation is 'making observations', and this would almost certainly be followed by 'on ...' or 'about ...'.

Comment: ... Ozdic doesn't give DO collocates; 'shout a warning', 'shout the order [to],  and 'shout the odds' are idiomatic.

Comment: Taken literally, they are a bunch of whores walking around in a house, telling everyone within earshot of there activities of the previous night.  Whether it's intended to be taken literally or not is unclear.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - So this is why you're not supposed to shout fire in a crowded theater?

Comment: @HotLicks Given the title of the work, my money is on literally.

Comment: @DanBron -- Alas, my money is on the whores.

Comment: @HotLicks I think they prefer you leave it on the dresser.

Comment: @Hot Licks The V + DO version _shout fire_ is almost certainly far rarer over here in the UK, in spite of our love for _cry wolf_. Interestingly, both versions ('The most stringent protection of free speech would not protect a man falsely shouting fire in a theater and causing a panic' [Holmes] and 'People have indeed falsely shouted "Fire!" in crowded public venues') are used in the relevant [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shouting_fire_in_a_crowded_theater). But this 'semi-quotative' usage often occurs in 'I wished her merry Christmas' vs 'I wished her "Merry Christmas" '.

Comment: Well, let's see: "shouted words of encouragement", "shouted obscenities", "shouted hello", "shouted goodbye", "shouted a greeting", "shouted his defiance", "shouted a command", "shouted a thousand curses", "shouted a few words of his own", "shouted a distress call", "shouted a slogan", "shouted a spell of immobilization".  And many more.

Comment: You shouldn't lose sight of the fact this was a _translation,_ and the original words were probably _gritaron comentarios_

Comment: @Gandalf a little different, it is "Las mujeres que malvendían sus cuerpos hasta el amanecer
se movían por la casa desde las once de la mañana, cuando ya la canícula del vitral
era insoportable, y tenían que hacer su vida doméstica caminando en pelotas por
toda la casa mientras comentaban a gritos sus aventuras de la noche." So, do you think comentaban has been translated as observations?

Comment: Thanks. I did a google-book search but couldn't find the quote. Yes, _Comentar_  could be translated that way. I think it has more to do with the Spanish usage and translation. Maybe it wasn't the best way to express it in English. It sounds to me more like the idea of "making loud ribald remarks".

Comment: _"Comentaban a gritos"_ is actually "talked about loudly, or shriekingly". where _comentar_ means to make observations or comments about. _Comentarios_ is "observations, or remarks". The translator is trying to convey García Marquez's style.

Comment: -1 because ODO says *2 A statement based on something one has seen, heard, or noticed.* How is this confusing? Anyway if one dictionary fails you try one or two more.

Answer (score 1):

**You are considering only one of the meanings of the word 'observation'.**

Among other meanings is:

> [a remark, comment, or statement based on what one has noticed or observed.](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/observation)

Given that definition the meaning of the quote should be obvious. The statements or remarks were shouted to one another.

Answer (score -1):

Part of the issue here is the translation from Spanish. This particular translation was done by Edith Grosman. [A quote from her on the process:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edith_Grossman)

> Fidelity is our noble purpose, but it does not have much, if anything, to do with what is called literal meaning. A translation can be faithful to tone and intention, to meaning. It **can rarely be faithful to words or syntax**, for these are peculiar to specific languages and are not transferable.

The actual Spanish text was:

> "Las mujeres que malvendían sus cuerpos hasta el amanecer se movían por la casa desde las once de la mañana, cuando ya la canícula del vitral era insoportable, y tenían que hacer su vida doméstica caminando en pelotas por toda la casa mientras comentaban a gritos sus aventuras de la noche."

...where *comentaban a gritos* could be better translated as “discussed in loud voices”, or “made loud remarks” to retain the original intent.

To understand the situation, you should know that a habit of some Latin women (especially whores—don’t ask me how I know) is to talk from room to room, so of course they need to raise their voices to do it.

Edith was only trying to convey something of García Marquez’s original tone, but it is possible she missed the intention.